# How do I update/fix the SASS and Compass $PATH to work with grunt-contrib-compass

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, grunt-contrib-compass

I am trying to run grunt-contrib-compass, but running into this error:

```
Warning: Couldn't find the `compass` binary. Make sure it's installed and in your $PATH Use --force to continue.
```

I've run:

- `sudo gem install compass`
- `sudo gem install sass`
- `sudo gem update --system`

When I do gem list, I get:

```
compass (1.0.1) 
rails (4.1.6)
sass (3.4.5, 3.3.4)
```

ruby:

```
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
```

Any suggestions or solutions on how to get grunt-contrib-compass working?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having this error too

Answer (score 4):

You have to install, first

```
sudo apt-get install ruby gem ruby-dev
```

second

```
sudo gem install compass
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you find your solution? I had the same error on Ubuntu 14.04.

Compass is a gem but you also need ruby-compass. If you do `compass -v`, it might say you don't have ruby-compass and need to install it. This was my case so I did `sudo apt-get install ruby-compass` which solved my problem.